# How to publish Maui iOS in VS Code

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-code, xamarin, maui

I've developed an iOS app in .Net Maui using VS Code.

Now I want to upload a build of my app to TestFlight.

I already have the app set up in App Store connect and I see the location to submit a build to TestFlight but I have no idea how to generate an ipa file and upload it through VS Code.

I see tutorials out there for Visual Studio and XCode but none for VS Code.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line to publish .NET MAUI app.

Example on Mac:

```
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="{insert the name of the code signing key}" -p:CodesignProvision="{insert the provisioning profile to use when signing the app bundle}"
```

Example on Windows:

```
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="insert the name of the code signing key" -p:CodesignProvision="insert the provisioning profile to use when signing the app bundle." -p:ServerAddress={macOS build host IP address} -p:ServerUser={macOS username} -p:ServerPassword={macOS password} -p:TcpPort=58181 -p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/{macOS username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/
```

Full how to: [Publish an iOS app using the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0)